# How do I make git clean (or smudge) modify files in my local repository

Tags: git, git-clean

I'm using git filters (specifically clean) to sort some xml files before checking them into the repository. However, the local files remain as they were - even a smudge filter doesn't do anything (presumably since they haven't been checked out).

Thus, if we do a diff using an IDE for example, it will compare against the file on disk - thus showing incorrect diffs vs what was actually committed to the repo.

Is there any way to force git to re-check-out on commit, so that the local file mirrors what is in the staging area?

Comment: You can pass the pathname to a filter with `%F` (`%f`? I forget) so you could have it duplicate its output to a temp file and replace the original when done.

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what you're doing and trying to do. For example, what does it mean to use `git clean` to sort XML files? That doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @CraigMcQueen I think he's referring to the 'clean' and 'smudge' directions of a content filter set by the `filter` attribute, not the `git clean` command

Comment: @jthill you are correct, I updated the question to clarify this. I think the idea of piping the output with `%f` will work, I will experiment with using `tee` for this purpose. Still wondering however if I'm not doing something untoward or un-git-like - is there a different paradigm I should be following? How do others deal with things like XML files or other text-based files that are generated through UI tools and that might change ordering of elements, making it difficult to monitor differences accordingly? Or do you use XML diff tools instead? I found some but most seemed to be paid..

Answer (score 0):

I [proposed an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21653524/6309) in order to force  the index to be checked out again.

But you can also [limit the checkout to only the files with a smudge filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37943650/6309).