# How to reference other config values in .gitconfig

Tags: bash, git, git-config

### TL;DR

How do I reference a `.gitconfig` config value in another config value?

**.gitconfig**

```
[filter "myFilter"]
    foo = Hello world
    bar = echo $(git config filter.myFilter.foo)
```

**bash**

```sh
$(git config filter.myFilter.bar)
# should print "Hello world"
```

---

### My problem

I am trying to write some `smudge`/`clean` filters (a la [Can git automatically switch between spaces and tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs)) so that on checkout, tabsizes are set to 4 spaces, and on commit, they're reverted to what's already in the repo.

The SO answers suggest this:

> ```sh
> git config --global filter.tabspace.smudge 'unexpand --tabs=4'
> git config --global filter.tabspace.clean 'expand --tabs=4'
> ```

Or the equivalent `.gitconfig` file:

> ```
> [filter "tabspace"]
>     smudge = 'unexpand --tabs=4'
>     clean = 'expand --tabs=4'
> ```

This works fine if you know that all of your remote repos use tabs.  I want to generalize it (and in the process, learn more about `git config`), so I can set a value, and the values in `~/.gitconfig` will do the rest.

---

### Desired behavior

My `~/.gitconfig` looks like

```
#...

[filter "tabspace"]
    repoTabs = false
    repoTabSize = 4
    smudge = # TODO
    clean = # TODO

#...
```

When I clone a repo that uses tabs or non-4 spaces, I run

```sh
# for repos that use tabs
git config filter.tabspace.repoTabs true

# for repos that use 2 spaces
git config filter.tabspace.repoTabSize 2
```

and then create a file at `.git/info/attributes` that looks like

```
*.js    filter=tabspace
*.jsx   filter=tabspace
*.ts    filter=tabspace
*.tsx   filter=tabspace
*.json  filter=tabspace
```

---

### Partial solution

The scripts I want to use for `smudge` and `clean` should be relatively straight forward (I've written these each on single lines, in my `~/.gitconfig` file in place of the two `# TODO`s):

```sh
# smudge
if [ `#filter.tabspace.repoTabs` == true ]; then
    expand --tabs=4
else
    unexpand --tabs=`#filter.tabspace.repoTabSize` | expand --tabs=4
fi

# clean
if [ `#filter.tabspace.repoTabs` == true ]; then
    unexpand --tabs=4
else
    unexpand --tabs=4 | expand --tabs=`#filter.tabspace.repoTabSize`
fi
```

What I can't for the life of me figure out is how to get the values of `filter.tabspace.repoTabs` and `filter.tabspace.repoTabSize` to work within the script.

My method for testing is setting `smudge = #my-script-here`, and then running

```sh
$(git config filter.tabspace.smudge)
```

where `#my-script-here` has been things like `echo $(git config filter.tabspace.repoTabSize)` with dozens of attempts to enclose various parts of the value with single quotes, double quotes, escaped double-quotes, and backticks instead of `$()`.  Everything I've tried either evaluates `$(git config filter.tabspace.repoTabSize)` literally or fails outright.

I also tried simply using `repoTabSize`, hoping it would just insert the scoped variable, but no such luck.

---

As a sanity check:

```sh
git config filter.tabspace.repoTabSize 2
echo $(git config filter.tabspace.repoTabSize)

# prints
2
```

I also checked that piping a value into an `if` statement does what I need it to, assuming that `git checkout` and `git commit` pipe the files through the values of `filter.tabspace.smudge` and `filter.tabspace.clean` respectively.

```sh
echo -e '\t'foo | if [ true ]; then expand --tabs=4; fi

# prints (with 4 spaces):
    foo
```

Answer (score 0):

It's terribly verbose, so I'd still like a better answer, but using `eval` and some escaped double-quotes I can achieve what I want.

In my partial solution scripts, I needed to replace:

```
`#filter.tabspace.repoTabs` -> $(eval "git config filter.tabspace.repoTabs")
`#filter.tabspace.repoTabSize` -> $(eval "git config filter.tabspace.repoTabSize")
```

Then I needed to wrap the value in double quotes--which also means escaping the double quotes in the `eval` expressions.

Final result:

```
[filter "tabspace"]
    repoTabs = false
    repoTabSize = 4
    smudge = "if [ $(eval \"git config filter.tabspace.repoTabs\") == true ]; then expand --tabs=4; else unexpand --tabs=$(eval \"git config filter.tabspace.repoTabSize\") | expand --tabs=4; fi"
    clean = "if [ $(eval \"git config filter.tabspace.repoTabs\") == true ]; then unexpand --tabs=4; else unexpand --tabs=4 | expand --tabs=$(eval \"git config filter.tabspace.repoTabSize\"); fi"
```

---

As an aside, the referenced SO question's answers didn't give a good method for forcing the smudge to be run.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21653524/3120446) was much better.

**Warning: don't do this if you have files that aren't committed.**

```
rm .git/index
git checkout HEAD -- "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more a matter of shell programming than anything else.

Note that `git config --get` gives you back an exit code to tell whether something was set:

```
$ git config --get branch.master.merge; echo $?
refs/heads/master
0
$ git config --get branch.master.marge; echo $?
1
```

You can add `--default <value>` but that defeats the exit code:

```
$ git config --get --default simpson branch.master.marge; echo $?
simpson
0
```

There is also `git config --get -t <type> <name>`, which converts the actual setting to a proper value and produces it, or produces an error (to stderr) and exits with failure, based on the supplied type:

```
$ git config --get -t bool core.bare; echo $?
false
0
$ git config --get -t bool branch.master.merge; echo $?
fatal: bad numeric config value 'refs/heads/master' for 'branch.master.merge' in file .git/config: invalid unit
128
```

So, in a shell script, you could simply test whether the value is set at all as your decision, or use a separate boolean as you are attempting:

```
#! /bin/sh
do_tabs=$(git config --get -t bool --default false filter.tabspace.repotabs) || exit
if $do_tabs; then
    tabsize=$(git config --get -t int --default 8 filter.tabspace.repotabsize) || exit
fi
```

or:

```
#! /bin/sh
tabsize=$(git config --get -t int filter.tabspace.size)
case $? in
0) do_tabs=true;;
1) do_tabs=false;;
*) exit;;
esac
```

Now, either way, you have two variables that capture both the desire ("should we do this tab thing?") and, if $do_tabs, the actual size, so now you can write:

```
case "#1" in)
--smudge) is_smudge=true;;
--clean) is_smudge=false;;
*) echo "run with --smudge or --clean"; exit 1;;
esac

if $is_smudge; then
    if $do_tabs; then
        expand --$tabsize
    fi
else
    ...
fi
```

(fill in the rest in the obvious way).  The resulting script can be invoked with:

```
[filter "tabspace"]
    smudge = script_name --smudge
    clean = script_name --clean
```

The argument (`$1`) determines the mode of operation and the two settings come from the config file, and the script reads stdin and writes stdout as required.

I have not attempted to reproduce your full code, though, as there's something very odd to me here:

> unexpand --tabs=4 | expand --tabs=[any number here]

The `unexpand` program will replace leading spaces with tabs as appropriate, with four spaces becoming one tab, 8 becoming 2, and so on; `expand` will then replace with some number of spaces.  If the `--tabs=` number is also 4, this whole thing is a big no-op.  But if the `--tabs=` is different, this takes a space-only file—which seems to be what you expect in all of your work-tree files—and *changes* the number of spaces when they're leading spaces.  That seems like a weird thing to do.  Does it not make more sense to put hard-tabs into the file at every 8 positions the way the rest of the system mostly expects?  If so, all `--unexpand` calls should have no arguments, and `--expand` can have no arguments as well, as the in-work-tree files always have spaces only.

Comment: It's 2:30am so I'll probably have to come back to figure out what you mean, but the logic for clean unexpanding and then reexpanding is that I don't know how many spaces the repo expects.  If it's 2, then I need to change all my 4-spaces to 2-spaces.  Afaik, `expand --tabs=2` won't work because there are no tabs in my files.  To figure out how many leading "tabs" there are, I convert my 4-spaces to tabs first as an intermediary step.

Comment: Ah, I think I'm misinterpreting what you're attempting to do, then. You're building a kind of less-functional clang-format or gofmt or whatever (but not for any specific language).